# If a line of text is separated into multiple text leaves in the accessibility tree, is it still accessible well?

Tags: reactjs, accessibility

Below is a picture of my current accessibility tree. You can see that the 4 text leaves in it are separated, but it still forms only one line of content. Is this still accessible well ("well" meaning screen readers can detect that they form one complete sentence), or **should all of the text leaves be combined into one leaf?**

[image: accessibility tree with 4 text leaves separated]

If they should be combined, **how can you concatenate variables into the text in React, while keeping it as one single leaf**? This is my current code: `<p>{cloudiness}% ({cloudinessDescription})</p>`

Comment: Answer to my second question: They can be combined by doing ``<p>{`${cloudiness}% (${cloudinessDescription})`}</p>``, but that's not ideal because it's more complicated.

Comment: Could you post the code after it has been parsed/interpreted by react ? It will certainly help answering the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How they are read aloud depends on the screen reader being used. VoiceOver reads it as one phrase, but that doesn't mean others will. Having it split up wouldn't be a nice experience, but it doesn't mean it's not accessible.

If you really want to make sure it's read as one phrase but don't like the noise of the template literal inside the JSX (I agree), why not define the string somewhere else until you are able to test on multiple screen readers?

```js
const cloudinessSummary = `${cloudiness}% (${cloudinessDescription})`;

return <p>{cloudinessSummary}</p>;
```